# Disable inline editing if value is present in php

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

Apologies if this question has been asked previously.

I am currently generating a basic table using PHP and have one cell where a user can add a comment.

When the user types a comment into the editable cell it saves it to the database table "TechComment column".

I want the editable cell to "disable editing" after the user entered the comment.

My code below:

Table Code

```
require_once "../linkd.php";

$sql = "select * from DispatchTech where  Technician = ? and convert(date, Inserted) = convert(date, 
getdate()) order by Completed ASC, DoneWhen";
$ses = $_SESSION['Username'];

$par = array($ses);
$stmt = sqlsrv_query($conn, $sql, $par);


if($stmt){
$count = 1;
while($row = sqlsrv_fetch_array($stmt, SQLSRV_FETCH_ASSOC)){

   $id = $row['Id'];
   $txt = $row['TechComment'];
?>

<tr>

<?PHP
if($row['Completed'] == NULL){
print "<td><button onclick=location.href='complete.php?Id=".$row['Id']."'>Complete</button></td>";
}
elseif($row['Completed'] != NULL){
print '<td><span align="center" style="font-size:15px;">&#9989;</span></td>';
}

if($row['Area'] == NULL){
print "<td><button onclick=location.href='arrive.php?Id=".$row['Id']."'>On Site</button></td>";
}else{
print "<td>";
print date_format(new DateTime($row['Area']), "H:i:s");
print "</td>";
}  
?>

<td><?php echo $row['TermID']; ?></td>
<td><?php echo $row['Location']; ?></td>
<td><?php echo $row['DMRef']; ?></td>
<td><?php echo $row['Error']; ?></td>
<td><?php echo $row['Description']; ?></td>
<td><?php echo date_format($row['Inserted'], "H:i:s") ?></td>
<td><div contentEditable='true' class="edit" id='TechComment_<?php echo $id; ?>'><?php echo $txt; ?> 
</div> </td>
<td><?php echo $row['Timeframe']; ?></td>
</tr>


<?PHP
$count ++;  
}
}
?>
```

Jquery/Ajax Code:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
$('.edit').click(function(){
$(this).addClass('editMode');
});

$(".edit").focusout(function(){
$(this).removeClass("editMode");
var id = this.id;
var split_id = id.split("_");
var field_TechComment = split_id[0];
var edit_id = split_id[1];
var value = $(this).text();


$.ajax({
url: 'update.php',
type: 'post',
data: { field:field_TechComment, value:value, id:edit_id },
success:function(response){
console.log('Save successfully'); 
}
}); 
});
});
```

I found this short jquery script that will do the trick but can't get it to work.

```
  $('.edit').editable(function (value, settings) {
    return value;
  });
```

Might it be because i'm using ajax?
I am not that familiar with ajax.

Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can achieve it by setting `contentEditable` to `false` in your ajax response, like:

```
$(".edit").focusout(function(){
$(this).removeClass("editMode");
var id = this.id;
var split_id = id.split("_");
var field_TechComment = split_id[0];
var edit_id = split_id[1];
var value = $(this).text();


$.ajax({
 url: 'update.php',
 type: 'post',
 data: { field:field_TechComment, value:value, id:edit_id },
 success:function(response){
   console.log('Save successfully'); 
   $('#'+id).prop('contenteditable', false );
 }
}); 
});
```

Comment: Thank you kindly for the assistance. I removed the "console.log('Save successfully'); " line and added the line you suggested and it worked.